# Uploading Large Updates CSV to mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

We are running Seibel CRM to capture the customer subscription. A daily extract of all customers' records is being sent to me on daily basis to do some analysis and to be used for other tasks. I need to upload the same file into my mySQL using a PHP page as this would be done by one of the supervisors.

The file is about 47MB and contain about 200,000 records. It increases by 500-550 records per day. The customer reference is his number. If the customer unsubscribe or his service get terminated, the customer number is assigned to another number after 3 months; this would mean that I either need to search for additions or changes.

I need help with the 1st time upload and the daily upload routine that need to take place.

Thanking you in advance,

Aziz

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like you. For my problem LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' INTO TABLE  was a good solution ( approximately 1 000 000 records). 
Upload file with php and then call the sql query. But the structure of the file must be the same as in the mysql table.

Kind Regards